# SyntaxError: Private field '#atributo' must be declared in an enclosing class

Tags: javascript, node.js, atributos, private

Criei as classes Funcionario e Diretor, sendo Gerente herdeira(filha) de Funcionários, mas ao instanciar um objeto Diretor obtive o seguinte erro: **SyntaxError: Private field '#bonificacao' must be declared in an enclosing class.**

Substitui os "#" utilizado nos atributos privados por "_" e funcionou. Os atributos privados com "#" não são herdados? Alguél sabe a razão para que não funcione?

OBS: Estou usando o Node.js v.14.2.0 para interpretar o código.

Segue abaixo as classes em questão:

```
// index.js
import { Funcionario } from "./funcionario/Funcionario.js";
import { Gerente } from "./funcionario/Gerente.js";
import { Diretor } from "./funcionario/Diretor.js";

const diretor = new Diretor(11122233345, "Roberto", 2000);
```

```
export class Funcionario {
    #bonificacao = 1;
    #cpf;
    #nome;
    #salario;
    #senha;

    constructor(cpf, nome, salario) {
        this.#cpf = cpf;
        this.#nome = nome;
        this.#salario = salario;
        if (this.constructor == Funcionario)
            throw new Error(
                "Não é permitida a instanciação da classe Funcionario diretamente."
            );
    }

    get senha() {
        return this.#senha;
    }

    cadastrarSenha(senha) {
        this.#senha = senha;
    }
}
```

```
import { Funcionario } from "./Funcionario.js";

export class Diretor extends Funcionario {
    constructor(cpf, nome, salario) {
        super(cpf, nome, salario);
        this.#bonificacao = 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A clássica confusão entre herança e private vs protected properties.

A classe Functionario tem o campo `#bonificacao` como privado, isto significa que somente o código interno daquela mesma classe tem acesso a ele.

A classe Diretor que está extendendo a classe Funcionario não tem acesso a este campo por que ele não é **protected** e sim **private**.

Mas não é o fim do mundo, se tu declarar o campo novamente na classe filha (como no codigo abaixo) tudo vai funcionar.

Tu pode rodar o código aqui no Browser clicando no botão azul **Executar** logo abaixo do código

```js
class Funcionario {
    #bonificacao = 1;
    #cpf;
    #nome;
    #salario;
    #senha;

    constructor(cpf, nome, salario) {
        this.#cpf = cpf;
        this.#nome = nome;
        this.#salario = salario;
        if (this.constructor == Funcionario)
            throw new Error(
                "Não é permitida a instanciação da classe Funcionario diretamente."
            );
    }

    get senha() {
        return this.#senha;
    }

    cadastrarSenha(senha) {
        this.#senha = senha;
    }
}

class Diretor extends Funcionario {
    #bonificacao;
    constructor(cpf, nome, salario) {
        super(cpf, nome, salario);
        this.#bonificacao = 2;
    }
    
    get bonificacao () { return this.#bonificacao }
}

const diretor = new Diretor('123.123.123.123', 'Daniel', 150_000)

console.log(diretor.bonificacao)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Mas eu quero que Diretor.js herde a variável bonificacao de Funcionario.js, assim, caso não haja o "this.#bonificacao = 2", quero que o valor padrão seja o definido na classe mãe. Se eu definir #bonificacao em Diretor.js, o valor será undefined. Há algum prefixo que determine que uma variável é protected, assim como # determina que a variável é private? Senão, devo usar como padrão do prefixo "_"  deixando as variáveis publicas e usando encapsulamento para a proteção das mesmas, ou há alguma outra forma de contornar isso?

Comment: Private attributes/fields é uma feature nova, e por muitos anos devs tinha que simular este recurso. Infelizmente, pra o teu caso, não há como declarar protected fields.